# Finding location where C++ namespace is included in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, namespaces

I am working on a large C++ project in Visual Studio, and it is reporting that an enum is ambiguous because an enum in a certain namespace (say foo) has the same name. As namespace foo should not be used in this file, I would like to know where the namespace is being added so that I can possibly remove it. How do I figure out the include chain to the C++ header that has the `using namespace foo`? I would prefer to be able to do this inside of Visual Studio if possible.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious the problem doesn't seem to be the declarations themselves, the problem seems to be that someone has put a `using namespace foo` where they shouldn't. This is why everybody advises to *never* put a `using` into your header files.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I know where the offending identifier is declared, however, it is declared in namespace foo, and if it wasn't for an erroneous `using namespace foo` line in a header, I wouldn't be getting this problem.

Comment: I believe there's a compiler option you can set to get the contents of the files after all pre-processor substitutions have occurred. Search through those files.

Comment: @MarkRansom It will even dump the pre-processed result to a file, search for the namespace foo.  There will be directives saying where files started and ended (pragmas), you can unroll it and work out the include chain.  Now the OP's problem is also that there are headers that `using namespace blah`, which is problematic for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want [/showIncludes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx).

On the other hand you may just want to do a find-in-all-files for "using namespace foo".

Or perhaps do both to track down which possible headers are actually being included at the problematic area.